# XML : Ribbon Button not aligning to the Right in Office Ribbon X Editor

Tags: html, excel, xml, vba, ribbonx

[Click here : To view the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij7fH.jpg)

Note : I'd like to align the button to the 'right'. Right now, the button is being displayed to the left! I've tried 'style' attribute which did not work!

```
<customUI xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
```

```
  <tab id = "Tab" label="Macros">
      
    <group id = "Screener" label = "Search!">

      <button 
              id = "ScreenerAddInMSExcel" 
              label = "Screener" 
              image = "Screener_Icon"
              size = "large" 
              style="float: right"
              onAction = "GetDataFromScreener"/>
              
    </group>
        
  </tab>

</tabs>
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no 'style' attribute.

Comment: @freeflow - Yeah....

Answer (score 0):

The Fluent UI doesn't provide such an attribute for the `button` control (element).

Read more about supported tags and attributes in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Fluent UI. I'm not aware of that!